# Change UIImageView position when rotate view

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

i'm trying to change the position of a UIImageView in iPad when i rotate the device, but i can't understand why sometime change and some time doesn't change, i want also detect when the view start what is the orientation so i can set the right position, but doens't work, this is the code:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSLog(@"%d",toInterfaceOrientation);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeShelfPosition:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:toInterfaceOrientation] waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)changeShelfPosition:(NSNumber *)orientation
{
    if (orientation.integerValue == 1 ) {

        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, 544, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);

    } else if (orientation.integerValue == 2) {
        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, 544, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);
    } else if (orientation.integerValue == 3) {
        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, 594, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);
    } else if (orientation.integerValue == 4) {
        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, 594, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == 0) {

    }//Default orientation
        //UI is in Default (Portrait) -- this is really a just a failsafe.
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.y, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);
    }
            //Do something if the orientation is in Portrait
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.y+50, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);
    }
                // Do something if Left
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.shelfImage3.frame = CGRectMake(self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.x, self.shelfImage3.frame.origin.y+50, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.width, self.shelfImage3.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access frames or other geometric properties in `viewDidLoad` and expect a consistent result, as the view geometry has not yet been set.

Try in `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: ok, and why doens't work also in this method - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: i found the problem, it's the autolayout option of iOS 6 i have disabled it in interface builder...